# What does `<<` mean when declaring a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, hiphop

I was looking at [this article](http://www.hiphop-php.com/wp/?p=113) about facebook's HipHop Virtual Machine (HHVM) when I noticed this line:

```
<?php
$u_bytes =
$p_bytes = 100 << 20;
```

I tested it by running `echo 100 << 20;` and the value was 104857600. What does `<< 20` do?

---

**Edit**

Based on the answers it's a bitwise operator (bit shift [left]). Example:

```
100       = 000000000000000000001100100
                                ^ `<< 20` moves this bit 20 bits to the left
104857600 = 110010000000000000000000000
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It will be extremely useful in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bit shift left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Bit_shifts).

You can learn more on how it works in PHP directly on PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php